# ruby rake guard task

Tags: ruby, rake, guard

Ruby noob - I need to have guard running in my rake tasks but I can't find a way to have it run in the background. It needs to run 2nd last, therefore having the `guard >` shell waiting for commands is preventing the final task from running, so calling `sh bundle exec guard` in the rake file is not an option. According to the documentation this should work:

```
  ##
  desc "Watch files"
  ##
  task :watcher do
    Guard.setup
    Guard::Dsl.evaluate_guardfile(:guardfile => 'Guardfile', :group => ['Frontend'])
    Guard.guards('copy').run_all
  end
  #end watch files
```

https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Use-Guard-programmatically-cookbook

Here is my Guardfile, in full, (in same dir as Rakefile)

```
# Any files created or modified in the 'source' directory
# will be copied to the 'target' directory. Update the
# guard as appropriate for your needs.
guard :copy, :from => 'src', :to => 'dist', 
            :mkpath => true, :verbose => true
```

But `rake watcher` returns an error:

```
07:02:31 - INFO - Using Guardfile at Guardfile.
07:02:31 - ERROR - Guard::Copy - cannot copy, no valid :to directories
rake aborted!
uncaught throw :task_has_failed
```

I have tried different hacks, too many to mention here, but all have returned the above `Guard::copy - cannot copy, no valid :to directories`. The `dist` directory definitely exists. Also if I call guard from the shell, inside rake or on cmd line, then it runs perfect, but leaves me with the `guard >` shell. Think my issue maybe a syntax error in the rake file? any help appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2):

Guard Copy does some initialization in the `#start` method, so you need to start the Guard before you can run it:

```
task :watcher do
  Guard.setup
  copy = Guard.guards('copy')
  copy.start
  copy.run_all
end
```

In addition there's no need to call `Guard::Dsl.evaluate_guardfile` anymore, that info on the wiki is outdated.

### Edit 1: Keep watching

When you want to watch the dir, then you need to start Guard:

```
task :watcher do
  Guard.start
  copy = Guard.guards('copy')
  copy.start
  copy.run_all
end
```

**Note:** If you setup Guard **and** start it afterwards, then Guard fails with `Hook with name 'load_guard_rc'`

### Edit 2: Really keep watching

Guard starts [Listen](https://github.com/guard/listen) in non blocking mode, so in order to make the call blocking, you need to wait for it:

```
task :watcher do
  Guard.start
  copy = Guard.guards('copy')
  copy.start
  copy.run_all
  while ::Guard.running do
    sleep 0.5
  end
end
```

If you also want to disable interactions, you can pass the `no_interactions` option:

```
Guard.start({ no_interactions: true })
```

The API is absolutely not optimal and I'll improve it for Guard 2 when we remove Ruby 1.8.7 support and some deprecated stuff.

Comment: @Netpirat your answer has brought me 50% there, cheers `rake watcher` now coppies everything from `src` to `dist` but then fails to watch the files. If i run `guard` from the cmd line the files are watched successfully. Could there be another call in the watcher:task needed, such as guard-listen?

Comment: @Coombesy If you also want the file watchers, you need to start Listen with `Guard.start`

Comment: thanks for the tip. If I replace `Guard.setup` with `Guard.start` then it will copy the files but still won't watch the folder. If I call both `setup` and `start` I get `Hook with name 'load_guard_rc' already defined!` - The guard file is also still working when I call `guard` from the shell

Comment: @Coombesy You can avoid the error by disabling the interactor, which you anyway don't need in the task: `Guard.setup({ no_interactions: true })`

Comment: Still no joy, i've updated the code in your answer to reflect the current rake file. `bundle exec guard` and `guard` are still working as expected, but `rake watcher` copies everything but still doesn't watch the folders :(